# Unregister FCM token for mutiple user in one app

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

in `Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) I m getting device token.and notification is coming .but in my app there is two user so i m sending notification for 2 user notification is coming.But i m logged in as 1 user. because both device id stored in my database and based on device id is fire base sent notification.so i want to restrict or unregistered fire base device  token  .if i m not logged in as 2user.i can delete that device id from database that is one solution. but some reason i cant delete for counting user it is required .so help me for this situation..thanks for helping

Comment: Is there any concern to keep it ?

Comment: Add GCM and FCM full names and associated tags. Rephrase the question to get something more understandable

Comment: yes when  any one will attempt to logout i will unregistered that tocken

Answer (score 0):

FCM is running on GCM as its core. The behavior related to GCM when an app is being uninstalled should still be the same for FCM.

When your app is uninstalled, it is the developer's responsibility to *unregister*/remove the corresponding registration token from your own App Server, along with the other actions (in your scenario, count the number of uninstalls) you need.

In turn, the FCM server will determine if the app is uninstalled and then invalidate the corresponding registration token. From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#lifetime):

> Finally, when FCM attempts to deliver a message to the device and the app was uninstalled, FCM discards that message right away and invalidates the registration token. Future attempts to send a message to that device results in a NotRegistered error.

Comment: @android_jain I think that was on point of what you were asking about. If not, do edit your post for more clarification and details.